# compass hand in hand with wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, compass-sass

I've got a dilemma. Compass is creating the output file `screen.css`(and ie, print) but Wordpress requires the name `style.css` as the default theme stylesheet. How can I solve this? Can I change the compass default ouput name, or can I change Wordpress defaul "input" stylesheet scource?

-- Update --

I did solve the problem. But not naturally. What you can do is that you temporarily create a style.css in your theme directory with the required information. After that you can customize the stylesheet link href in the header.php just as usual. So the style.css in the root theme directory is just "fake".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the path to the css file in `header.php`

change :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/style/sheet.css" />
```

Comment: "Broken Themes, Description: Stylesheet is missing." Because it itsn't in the style.css format

Comment: where is it showing you that error?

Comment: In the wordpress admin / themes

Comment: which theme are you using? I can take a look